# Why is stack overflow not occuring?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, memset

**Ubuntu**

```
ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 62202
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62202
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

As mentioned above max stack size is 8MB

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int abc[2048002];
  memset(abc,0,2048002*4);

}
```

In above program, I have allocated more than 8MB, even though the stack size is exceeded (max 8MB), I am  not getting segmentation fault. So can anyone explain why I am not getting stack overflow in above scenario?

Comment: Are you sure that the entire program isn't just optimized away?

Comment: Memory not allocated unless you do memset. Do memset you should get stack overflow

Comment: 1. The stacksize is 8M not 8K as John said. 2. *nix system does not actually allocate memory unless you try to access (read/write) it. So should do memset or printf. 3. You are allocating on the `heap`, not `stack`

Comment: Stacksize is 8K, kilobytes ==> 8 Mb.   John's remark looks right to me.

Comment: After edit: your stack use is only 8,000 kb. Still no overflow; there is 192 kb of free space.

Comment: That's just *less* than 8MB (assuming a 4-byte `int`) - 8MB would be 2097152. But even if it did overflow, there's no guarantee that that would give a visible error; it might crash, or it might just overwrite memory that it shouldn't, or it might be optimised to do nothing.

Comment: Right. [Detect stack overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828677/detect-stack-overflows) mentions a few possibilities (e.g., page boundaries), but without any of these, your program may exhibit *any* result -- including "appearing to work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
```

That's 8192 kilobytes, or 8 megabytes.

Comment: So you're saying it would blow the stack if his math was right?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  His math isn't just a little off; it's a lot off.

Comment: int abc[2048000], it means we can allocate maximum of 4*2048000 bytes , if we exceeded one byte more than it should throw segmentation fault? but in my case it is not happening. can you explain, why it is not behaving like that even we increase one byte more than max limit

Comment: I have not tested it to confirm, but you probably want to multiply by 1024 instead of 1000.